# Replacing sendSynchronousRequest with NSURLSession in command line tools

Tags: command-line, synchronization, nsurlsession

Trying to replace deprecated sendSynchronousRequest calls in several **command line tools** I have written.  The completionHandler is not getting called.  Based on somewhat similar questions, I have tried using a semaphore, but still no joy. (Most questions posted concern apps, not command line tools.)  Appreciate any help.  Here's my code snippet:

```
void ebayApiCall(NSMutableURLRequest * request, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
                                   ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"\nCompletionHandler\n");
                                       responseFromEbay = data; //responseFromEbay is global
                                       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                                   }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call `[dataTask resume]` **before** waiting on the semaphore.

Comment: This fixed it!  Thanks!  Wonder how the example I found this from ever worked?  (Sorry I don't have enough points to up vote you :-(

Comment: Since I made the switch to use NSURLSessionDataTask, I have started to receive occasional error messages like:   "INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /Users/rick/Library/Caches/EbayPricing/fsCachedData/B401D746-49F1-4980-BD67-7AD0DC0E4D47. Errno: 2"   Any ideas on this?  I never got that error before switching from synchronous calls to async calls. I put a 1 second delay after the [datatask resume] and it reduced the frequency of the errors, but it also slows my program!